# Gdk-CRITICAL **: 10:33:28.827: gdk_cursor_new_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, gdk

I has run the following code by VSCode:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

a = np.array([2, 4, 5])
plt.plot(a)
print('Hello')
```

Its output didn't show matplotlib figure but still print 'Hello'. This is output log:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(demo.py:16992): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 10:33:28.827: gdk_cursor_new_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
Hello
```

I run this code by VSCode, Ubuntu 20.04. But when I run by Spyder3, It shows the figure normally.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know VSCode but I guess that it does not make use of more sophisticated (Qt) consoles which can display matplotlib figures. This is the case for Spyder if I remember correctly.

Quick matplotlib intro:

- Actually your graph is plotted but not shown
- Usually you can display your plot in a separate window with `plt.show()`. Then the console is "locked". By closing the window you "delete" your plot. So new "lines" (e.g. `plt.plot(a+1)`) will be plotted in a new window without your previous data.
- You can start the interactive mode by calling `plt.ion()` (deactive with `plt.ioff()`). Then `plt.show()` does **not** lock your console
- Instead of plotting you can save it directly with `plt.savefig("filename.png")`. Perhaps you want to set the backend and prevent it from loading the GTK stuff. Then you don't get the Gdk-CRITICAL message. Insert `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg')` before you import `pyplot`

Does it solve your problem?

If not it may be helpful to answer the following:

- What happends when you change your (interactive) backend? Tip: read the help `help(matplotlib.use)` (of course after loading `import matplotlib`)
- What is your default backend? `matplotlib.get_backend()`

Comment: I was already saving to a file, but the suggestion of adding matplotlib.use('agg') removed the warning.  As the post indicates, it must be done before importing pyplot.